# How can I strip invalid data with Yup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

Is it possible with Yup to validate an object and keep all valid data and ignore invalid data and strip them?

In the following example I would like to keep `jimmy` and `name` because it is valid and strip `age` from result object, as it is invalid

```
import { object, string, number, date, InferType } from 'yup';

const userSchema = object({
  name: string().required(),
  age: number().required().positive().integer(),
  email: string().email(),
  website: string().url().nullable(),
  createdOn: date().default(() => new Date()),
});
```

```
const parsedUser = await userSchema.validate(
  {
    name: 'jimmy',
    age: -1,
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
userSchema.validate(data)
.then(validData => {
// The promise resolves with the valid data
console.log('Valid data:', validData);

// You can now use validData, which contains only valid fields.
})
.catch(errors => {
// The promise rejects with an array of validation errors
console.error('Validation errors:', errors);

// Here you can choose to handle the errors or strip the invalid data.
const strippedData = { ...data };
for (const error of errors) {
  const { path } = error;
  delete strippedData[path];
}

console.log('Stripped data:', strippedData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to extract sub-schemas from `userSchema.fields` and iterate over them

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can achieve this behavior with Yup by using the stripUnknown option. Setting stripUnknown to true will remove any keys in the input object that are not defined in your schema. In your case, it will remove the "age" key because it doesn't match the schema, and it will keep the other valid keys such as "name."

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
import { object, string, number, date } from 'yup';

const userSchema = object({
  name: string().required(),
  age: number().required().positive().integer(),
  email: string().email(),
  website: string().url().nullable(),
  createdOn: date().default(() => new Date()),
});

const inputData = {
  name: 'jimmy',
  age: -1,
};

const parsedUser = await userSchema.validate(inputData, { stripUnknown: true });

console.log(parsedUser);
```

With stripUnknown: true, the "age" key will be removed from the parsedUser object because it's not part of the schema, and you will only get the following output:

```
{
  name: 'jimmy'
}
```

Comment: Error `ValidationError: age must be a positive number`. Age is not unknown as it is defined in the schema

Comment: Nothing about this answer seems like it should have been flagged as "Not an Answer" or "Very Low Quality." Please do not delete this from the review queue.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the stripUnknown options in yup.

```
const options = {
  stripUnknown :true
}

const parsedUser = await userSchema.validate(
  {
    name: 'jimmy',
    age: -1,
  },options
);
```

Comment: Error `ValidationError: age must be a positive number`. Age is not unknown as it is defined in the schema